# React State does'nt refresh with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

I got an issue with my componant. I map through an array of elements to get their respective id. Then, in useEffect(), I make an API call for each of them to store an information in an array.

Each time my component change, the state is set successfully. However, whenI refresh the page, nothing happens, the state stays empty. I know it's about the asynchronous nature of useEffect but I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Here is my code :

```
  const [array, setArray] = useState([])
  const ids = ['id1','id2',...]

  const apiCall = () => {

    const getElements = async (ids) => {
      const allPromises = ids.map(id => Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/tickets/metrics/" + id))
      const dataElements = await Promise.all(allPromises)
      const responseDataElements = dataElements.map(response => response.data.metric)
      setArray(() => responseDataElements)
  }
  getElements(idTickets);
  }

  const useMountEffect = (apiCall) => useEffect(apiCall, [])

  useMountEffect(apiCall)
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried a different approach. I created a function in a file :

```
    const datas = []

    ids.map(ticket => {
     
      Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/tickets/metrics/" + id).then((Response) => {
        const data = Response.data
        datas.push(data)
      })
    })
   
    return data
  }
```

Then in my parent component I pass this function :

`<Child prop={TempsResolution(tickets)} />`

Finally I got it in my component :

```
const [state, setState] = useState([])

// On page loading I got my values in an array
console.log(prop)

useEffect (()=>{
  // On page loading empty array appears
  setState(prop)
}, [])


  return (
    <div className="bloc grid-x large-8 cell align-middle align-center mgin-top">
      <div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p>nombre de tickets</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I still have the issue, I really cant figured out what's wrong

Comment: where is your react component, and you are using useEffect like some normal function which is not right way to use hooks.

Comment: I would not define a custom hook within a component. Anything that does not need to be within in a component is best to be have it outside of it, otherwise each rerender you would create a new function. Not sure whether that's the problem though. Do you have some logs of ht promises/ids that are called on mount? Maybe that can give us a hint

Answer (score 0):

In you question Headline and the description is different as I could see. but if you're asking about useEffect not runs in state change. here is my solution.

In the useEffect hook the final parameter is the dependancy array.

useEffect(()=>{},[this_is_dependancy_array])

if you put this to be an empty array, it will only be invoke once. if you need it to be invoked many times based on any of the state change you need to put that state variable inside the dependancy array.

assume you need to re-render based on the count changes

```
const [count,setCount] = useState(0)

useEffect(()=>{},[count]}
```

the above example will re-render each time when count changes.

Comment: I believe he wants to call the api only once to populate his state

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As Radika says, I want to populate my state with the API call. But it works only when I change something in the file. If add even a console.log, save the file, it works, my state is fill with the API datas. But if a mage a page refresh the API call is not made

Answer (score 0):

You got hooks quite wrong way, you have 2 solution to solve the same.

1 st

```
const getElements = async (ids) => {
  const allPromises = ids.map((id) => Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/tickets/metrics/' + id))
  const dataElements = await Promise.all(allPromises)
  return dataElements.map((response) => response.data.metric)
}

export function MyComponent() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const ids = ['id1', 'id2']
    
    getElements(ids)
      .then((arr) => setArray(arr))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
        setArray([])
      })
  }, [])

  return <div></div>
}
```

2nd way

```
export function MyComponent() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([])
 
  const getElements2 = async (ids) => {
    try {
      const allPromises = ids.map((id) => Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/tickets/metrics/' + id))
      const dataElements = await Promise.all(allPromises)
      const responseDataElements = dataElements.map((response) => response.data.metric)
      setArray(responseDataElements)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      setArray([])
    }
  }


 useEffect(() => {
    const ids = ['id1', 'id2']
    
    console.log('component loaded', new Date())
    
    getElements2(ids)
    
  }, []) 

  return <div>
     {array.map((_, index) => <div>{index}</div>)} 
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have the issue : API calls aren't made when page is reload. But it works when I change something in the file (like add a console.log etc.)

Comment: @ArthurFortin That should not be happening, I have updated 2nd version code, try it out and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately no. I see the console log but the issue is still the same. On page reload nothing happens, have to make a change in the component. I think that the problem is in the function getElements and the API

Comment: @ArthurFortin do you see `component loaded...` in console after reloading the page ??

Comment: Yes absolutely : `component loaded Thu Aug 04 2022 14:53:20 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)`

Comment: @ArthurFortin then useEffect is working fine, its calling your api & console.log function everytime you referesh, seems there is something issue with backend.  Check `network` tab of dev tools (click on `xhr` filter),

Comment: Nothing appears...

Comment: @ArthurFortin you need to referesh page, it doesn't show requests made before opening network tab of dev tools.

Comment: I tried another approach as you see in my post edit. With this approach I still have an issue but the api is calling everytime.

Comment: @ArthurFortin you need to add `prop` in useEffect's dependency list (`useEffect(..., [prop])`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the solution. First like @bogdanoff said, use useEffect as a function was not a good approach. So I put all the api calls on server side, instead of divided it in different components and use a `promise.all` to fetch data. Here is the logic :

```
axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      const idTickets = []
      Object.values(response).map(ticket => {
        idTickets.push(ticket.id)
      })
      return idTickets
    })

return Promise.all(response.map(id => {
        var config2 = {
          method: 'get',
          url: '.../api',
          headers: {
            ...
          }
        };

      return  axios(config2)
          .then(function (response) {
            const theData = response.data
            return theData
          })

          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }))

.then(function (response) {
      res.send(response)
    })
```

Thanks a lot for your help